# Equals() for double values in .NET. Wrong implementation or not?

Tags: c#, equals

I always thought that "==" and Equals() give same result for double values...But this is not true

Example

```
    var a = Double.NaN;

    Console.WriteLine(a == a);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Prints "False"

```
    var a = Double.NaN;

    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(a));
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Prints "True"!

So, **why Equals() method implementation for floating point numbers does not follow floating point numbers specification, which says that if number is NaN - it is not equal to anything, even to itself?**

P.S I merged my questions and will delete another about NaN's as soon as possible

P.P.S 
Equals realization (.NET 4, thanks to Ani)

```
public bool Equals(double obj)
{
    return ((obj == this) || (IsNaN(obj) && IsNaN(this)));
}
```